# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR for large png files on throttled/slow connection

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, playcanvas

I'm having problem's loading large png texture files for a playcanvas app when the connection is bad.
For some reason chromium browser's say the request fails with net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I've tested this with Google Chrome (Version 92.0.4515.131) and Microsoft Edge (Version 92.0.902.67).
Firefox doesn't have this problem and loads the files correctly.

I've searched quite a while for a solution, but couldn't find anything. It seem's to me that this is actually the normal behaviour in chromium.

Here is a excerpt of the network analysis tab:

[image: Network Tab Excerpt]

**EDIT:**
After further investigation with `chrome://net-export` i get this error:

```
...

t=22930 [st= 9839]      HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                        --> delta = 2701
                        --> stream_id = 109
                        --> window_size = 5748580
t=22930 [st= 9839]      HTTP2_STREAM_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                        --> delta = 384
                        --> stream_id = 109
                        --> window_size = 5748964
t=22930 [st= 9839]   -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY
t=25482 [st=12391]    HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR
                      --> description = "Server reset stream."
                      --> net_error = "ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
                      --> stream_id = 109
t=35602 [st=22511]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                      --> byte_count = 65536
t=35602 [st=22511]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=1]
t=45674 [st=32583]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                      --> byte_count = 65536
t=45675 [st=32584]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=53971 [st=40880]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                      --> byte_count = 65536
...
t=76985 [st=63894]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=80643 [st=67552]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                      --> byte_count = 65536
t=80643 [st=67552]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=83012 [st=69921]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                      --> byte_count = 57844
t=83012 [st=69921]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
                      --> net_error = -337 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=83012 [st=69921]    FAILED
                      --> net_error = -337 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
t=83012 [st=69921] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                    --> net_error = -337 (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)
```

**EDIT 2:** I've created a chromium issue for this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1237907

Comment: have you had a solution for this sir?

Comment: I've created an issue in the chromium bug forum: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1237907 Unfortunetly the priority of it is set to least urgent :/ If you have the same problem maybe you can add it to the issue